# finding max of many columns using proc sql statement

Tags: sas

I am trying to write a PROC SQL query in SAS to determine maximum of many columns starting with a particular letter (say RF*). The existing proc means statement which i have goes like this.

```
proc means data = input_table nway noprint missing;
   var age x y z RF: ST: ;
   class a b c;
   output out = output_table (drop = _type_ _freq_) max=;
run;
```

Where the columns RF: refers to all columns starting with RF and likewise for ST. I was wondering if there is something similar in PROC SQL, which i can use?

Thanks!

Comment: You may have to use dynamic SQL. There is a write-up on it here: http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/070-2012.pdf

Comment: This statement is a part of macro, and I am running it multiple times, so dynamic SQL might make it even more complex. Is there any work around other than this?

Comment: The only other way I know to make that work in PROC SQL would be to normalize ("unpivot") your data so that the columns are now in rows. That may not be feasible depending on your dataset format.

Comment: Why the switch if you have multiple variables, this is what SAS does best?

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic SQL is indeed the way to go with this, if you must use SQL. The good news is that you can do it all in one proc sql call using only one macro variable, e.g.:

```
proc sql noprint;
  select catx(' ','max(',name,') as',name) into :MAX_LIST separated by ','
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname = 'SASHELP' 
  and memname = 'CLASS'
  and type = 'num'
  /*eq: is not available in proc sql in my version of SAS, but we can use substr to match partial variable names*/ 
  and upcase(substr(name,1,1)) in ('A','W') /*Match all numeric vars that have names starting with A or W*/
  ;
  create table want as select SEX, &MAX_LIST
    from sashelp.class
    group by SEX;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps!